# group_concat by combining column values of two table

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, union, group-concat

I am trying to combine columns between two tables and concat them. While I am able to use `group_concat` on the columns which are specific to just one table but there is also a column for which I need to combine from `table1.role_id` and `table2.role_id` and join the result with specific delimiter.

I am using sqlite db.

SQL Fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f58a3/2)

**Table1**

| name | role_id | dep_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | d1 |
| a | 1 | d2 |
| b | 2 | d3 |
| b | 3 | d5 |
| c | 3 | d4 |

**Table2**

| name | role_id | ipv6 | ipv4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | ipv6_1 | ipv4_1 |
| a | 2 | ipv6_2 | ipv4_1 |
| b | 7 | ipv6_3 | ipv4_2 |
| b | 7 | ipv6_7 | ipv4_8 |
| e | 2 | ipv6_4 | ipv4_3 |

The query I have come up with

```
select t1.name,
          -- combine role_id column from both the tables and do group_concat on it??
          group_concat(DISTINCT t1.dep_id),
          group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv6),
          group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv4)
from       table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
        on t1.name = t2.name
group by t1.name
```

**Current query output**

| name | group_concat(DISTINCT t1.dep_id) | group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv6) | group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | d1,d2 | ipv6_1,ipv6_2 | ipv4_1 |
| b | d3,d5 | ipv6_3,ipv6_7 | ipv4_2,ipv4_8 |

Expected Result

| name | CONCAT_role_id | group_concat(DISTINCT t1.dep_id) | group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv6) | group_concat(DISTINCT t2.ipv4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1,2 | d1,d2 | ipv6_1,ipv6_2 | ipv4_1 |
| b | 2,3,7 | d3,d5 | ipv6_3,ipv6_7 | ipv4_2,ipv4_8 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a join use `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH
  common_names AS (SELECT name FROM table1 INTERSECT SELECT name FROM table2),
  cte AS (
    SELECT name, role_id, dep_id, null ipv6, null ipv4 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, role_id, null, ipv6, ipv4 FROM table2
  )
SELECT name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT role_id) roles,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dep_id) deps,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ipv6) ipv6s,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ipv4) ipv4s
FROM cte
WHERE name IN common_names
GROUP BY name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=91d946510a19c111891a2f6aa15aecbb).

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I am worried about doing `UNION ALL` is that the each table comes to around 50GB in size. I have indexed based on `name` column. Can you please suggest if this query would be efficient enough to run on such a large table or should I try considering any other parameters to ensure this query runs fast enough.

Comment: @chidori the index may help to filter the tables, but SQLite performs poorly for large datasets when it comes to UNION and aggregation with string manipulation like GROUP_CONCAT(). Of course you can test it.